# ldd does not show the dependency which make then needs

Tags: c++, compilation, ldd

I have the program which needs v2xmvtest.so. When i try to build it via make i get  [undefined reference to *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0KM2.png)
Seems like that function from libssl1.0. (If i install it, it's built fine)

But i do not see the place where these function are used. More than that, when i try [ldd v2xmvtest.so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sOCU.png) it does show only libvssl1.1 dependency.

Summary:

1. Is there a way to find out where those finctions from libvssl1.0 are used in the program ? (i have source code of the v2xmvtest.so and try to search, but there no any of these)
2. I need a description why ldd does not show me libssl1.0 dependency, but during linkning it's needed

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Libraries are not required to fully define used symbols. For instance you can have `lib.cpp`:

```
int foo();

int bar(int x)
{
    return x + foo();
}
```

and it compiles even `foo` is actually not defined yet:

```
g++ lib.cpp -shared -o lib.so
```

Then you can have main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int bar(int);

int foo()
{
  return 10;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << bar(42) << std::endl;
}
```

which defines `foo` and compiles successfully with lib.so:

```
g++ main.cpp lib.so -o main
```

The `foo` function in lib.so is expected just to be provided when the application is linked and is not specified where exactly from, even not necessary from a library.

You can check for undefined symbols in a library using [nm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) tool:

```
nm -C -u lib.so 
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U foo()
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.17
                 w __gmon_start__
```

And finally you can force gcc to ensure no undefined symbols are used by the object files by compiling with `-Wl,-z,defs` [linker flag](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

```
g++ lib.cpp -shared -Wl,-z,defs -o lib.so
...
lib.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `foo()'
```